# Define plot elements size in mm (R)

Tags: r

I am preparing figures in R for submission to a journal. Required formatting is given in mm (line width = 0.5mm, symbols = 3mm, etc).

I know how to define the figure size in mm, and to manage line width and symbol size with respectively lwd and cex, either in par() or within the plot function. I also found how to convert points to mm. However I don't know how to define line weight, text size, etc. precisely, and not "scaling up" as usual (eg. I want lwd = 0.5mm, not lwd = 1.2 x the default size).

I hope I am clear enough =)

Here is my code :

```
jpeg(paste('path-to-figure.jpg'), width=15, height=7)

plot(x, y, main = 'TITLE', xlab = "X NAME",ylab = 'Y NAME', ylim = c(0,180), xlim = c(0, 4)pch = 1)

dev.off()
```

Many Thanks !

Comment: This might not be a programming recommendation but I find it simpler to save the plot as a SVG file and then open it with Inkscape (or any other .svg image software) to edit those things of the plot manually. It's longer and interactive but you would have total control of dimension and position in whatever unit you desire.

Comment: That is what I first wanted to do... but I would probably need to do that quite a few times, and it might be really time-consuming. Also Inkscape just takes for ever just to open one image....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line widths in the standard `jpeg`, `png` etc. graphics devices are defined in 1/96 of an inch. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html . The same is true for `pdf` but may vary for other devices. 0.5 mm = 0.5 / 25.4 * 96 = 1.890 96ths of an inch. So you would use `lwd = 1.89`.

You could also consider using `ggplot2` since `size` within that is in mm anyway.

E.g.

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(size = 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I will use your first solution.